# Trouble when install Watchman on Linux 16.04

Tags: react-native, watchman

I'm trying to install watchman for React Native and I've followed the [Watchman docs](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html)...

```
$ git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
$ cd watchman
$ git checkout v4.9.0  # the latest stable release
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Below is the error after try `./configure`

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please put you error as text here, not with an image.

Comment: Also, since the error says "unsafe absolute working directory name" it might help to include the full path of the directory where the installation is happening

Comment: try to install watchman version 4.5.0. it will help.
$ git checkout v4.5.0